# MySQL finding MAX of a given field and returning the entire row

Tags: mysql, weather

## Introduction

Hi,
I have a weather station that records the current weather every half an hour.
Among other sensors, it has a thermometer. It is the subject in this enquiry.
I have summarized the fields of my table, but please be aware that `HiTemp` field stores the maximum temperature.

## Situation

Given the following table structure in a SQL query

```
CREATE TABLE weather (
    Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    HiTemp FLOAT,
    Date VARCHAR(8),
    Time VARCHAR(5),
    Epoch BIGINT
);
```

**Note that** `HiTemp` is stored in celsius degrees, `Date` follows `dd/mm/YY` format and `Time` is stored in CET (GMT+1) timezone
Therefore, a sample record would be..

```
1, 19, "13/12/19", "13:00", 1576238400
```

My goal is to sort through the records and find the maximum value of `HiTemp` along its other fields for every year in the table.
To find unique years a simple substring on `Date` works fine

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Date, -2) AS Year FROM weather GROUP BY Year;
```

I was thinking to use a `PROCEDURE` (function) to be able to use some kind of loop to go over the years
This query right here is the closest to my goal I have been able to figure out on my own

```
SELECT MAX(HiTemp) MaxTemp, SUBSTR(Date, -2) Year, Date, Time FROM weather GROUP BY Year;
```

Problem here is that as far as I know `MAX` is a group function and the other selected fields are irrelevant to its value
Nevertheless, the output of this query would have a format like the following

```
40.1, 19, "28/06/19", "17:00"
37.5, 18, "04/08/18", "14:00"
35.5, 17, "05/08/17", "15:30"
```

**Note that** these records are correct in the sense that the resulting selected fields belong to the very same record (they were handpicked)

Any ideas? Subqueries, Joins, Procedures.. Any insight on this is very much appreciated, I'm pretty lost at this point.
Thanks.

Comment: which is the column for  40,1, 37.5 .. si not clear ..

Comment: Store dates using proper date data types.

Comment: @scaisEdge that is the temperature, please take a look at the above query for field reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a query with a subquery for max temp  group by year

```
select  * from  weather w
INNER JOIN  ( 
  select  MAX(HiTemp) MaxTemp,  SUBSTR(Date, -2) Year 
  FROM weather GROUP BY Year

  ) t on t.MaxTemp = w.HiTemp and t.year =  SUBSTR(w.Date, -2)
```

or

```
select  w.HiTemp, t.Year, w.date, w.time  from  weather w
INNER JOIN  ( 
  select  MAX(HiTemp) MaxTemp,  SUBSTR(Date, -2) Year 
  FROM weather GROUP BY Year

  ) t on t.MaxTemp = w.HiTemp and t.year =  SUBSTR(w.Date, -2) Year
```

Comment: Perfect! Except the very last substring aliases. But it doesn't matter. I added a group by year at the end of the query to ensure I'm getting non duplicated years.   This is the final query if you wonder  `SELECT * FROM weather w INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(HiTemp) MaxTemp, SUBSTR(Date, -2) Year FROM weather GROUP BY Year) t ON t.Maxtemp = w.HiTemp AND t.Year = SUBSTR(w.Date, -2) GROUP BY SUBSTR(Date, -2)`